# Question regarding identity matrix - $I_n$ and $I_m$ - Determinant ) - Prove B matrix is squared and invertible

Tags: matrices, determinant, inverse

question regarding Determinant of Identity matrix.
I have a question regarding:
A is $m_xn$, B is $n_xm$
$$AB=I_m$$
$$BA=I_n$$
I have to prove B is invertible and squared.
I saw some solutions here with Trace and others, but I wanted to try a solution of my own, with determinants. is it possible? I tried this:
$$BA=I_n$$
$$BAB=I_nB$$
$$BI_m=I_n$$
$$|B||I_m|=|I_n||B|$$
$$|B|[|I_m|-|I_n|]=0$$

But here I was stuck, i tried maybe suppose in negative,  but still, cant continiue from here... since I dont have any more information.
Is there any way of continuing? any tip? without using trace, since I would have never, but really never thought of such a thing, I never used trace in my life, only if it was asked.

Comment: @daw sorry, i didnt understand? just change M and N to mxn?

Comment: @daw yea, but in order to show m=n, I need to prove using trace, which is not my point here. I want to prove without using trace method.

Comment: @TryingToMath You do not need to use trace to prove that $m=n$, you only need to use rank. To be honest I can't even see right now how you would use trace to prove it. More importantly your method does not work as the determinant is only defined for square matrices so you can't use the determinant to prove that a matrix is square as that is circular reasoning.

Comment: Ohh righttt, determinant is for square matrix only, omg I am an idiot... thanks!!
forgot about it totaly.

Comment: @Fishbane oh and regarding the rank.
what do you mean?
The only information I can get is Rank AB is equal to m
Rank Ba is equal to n. How does it help me? I cant say m=n because of it.

Comment: Given $2$ matrices $A,B$ with ranks $r$ and $k$ we know that the rank of $AB$ is $\min(r,k)$. Given that the identity matrix has full rank we conclude that in your problem the rank of $A$ and $B$ must be the same.

Comment: @Fishbane Ohh rightt, the rank of multiplication is the lowest of the two matrices.
So its $n$ and $m$ as you say, but the question is, how do you know who is the minimum? regarding the identity, I thought of it too, but its not trivial, I need to prove it somehow, I cant say just that ( I think )

Comment: The first thing to note is that rank $AB$ and rank $BA$ are the same, call that rank $n_0$. Now by the first equation we have $n_0=m$, and by the second we have $n_0=n$. Therefore we have $n=m$ and the result is now trivial by the definition of an invertible matrix.

Comment: Yea I understand this, I guess it is trivial, I thought I needed a more complicated proof, thank you :)
I will try!!

Comment: No problem, hope I helped.

Comment: @Fishbane you did!! thanks :)